# jQuery jBox doesn't load content from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, jbox

Quick question, I having problem loading a div in my jBox (A simple jquery popup script). This is the code I'm using

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MJBox = new jBox('Modal', {
        attach: $('#modalDragOnTitle'),
        width: 300,
        height: 450,
        title: 'Create new advertisement',
        overlay: true,
        draggable: 'title' });
    MJBox.setContent($('#modal-content-create-ad'));
});
</script>
<div id="modal-content-create-ad" style="display:none;">Hello this a div</div>
```

But if I put my text in setContent is works, code is like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MJBox = new jBox('Modal', {
        attach: $('#modalDragOnTitle'),
        width: 300,
        height: 450,
        title: 'Create new advertisement',
        overlay: true,
        draggable: 'title' });
    MJBox.setContent('Hello this is a div');
});
</script>
```

Anybody how has an idea to get this to work? I want the content of the div to load in the js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set content of modal-content-create-ad in MJBOX so use html function.

```
MJBox.setContent($('#modal-content-create-ad').html());
```